# How to run old build android application on new version of android?

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-api-levels

I know it seems odd to ask this question but i am facing an issue and finding its workaround.

I have an android application build to target **Marshmallow (android OS v 6.0)**, is there any way that i will be able to run this application on **Android-10 (android OS v 10)**.

> *I have lost its source code accidentally, so its impossible to upgrade the app to latest version.*

I can use android emulator for this purpose but that will be run on windows. I want to run on Android operating system

Any help much be appreciated

Comment: What kind of problem you're facing if you try to run the APK on Android10? P.S. Theoretically you can use [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to extract APK's content and rebuild it for new `targetdSdk`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's supposed to work fine on android 10